# Draw only corner of a rectangle

Tags: c#, picturebox, rectangles, drawrectangle

I used

```
Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red);
pen.DashStyle = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.Dot;
```

to shape the border of rectangle but now I only need to show the corner of that rectangle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can draw it by yourself by `DrawLine` function in `Paint` event handler, something like this:

```
Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red);

private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.pictureBox1_Paint);

    pen.DashStyle = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.Dot;
}

private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;

    g.DrawLine(pen, 0, 0, pictureBox1.Right, 0);

    g.DrawLine(pen, 0, 0, 0, pictureBox1.Bottom);
}
```

It's a use case, maybe you need other coordinates, but you can fix it easily.

Answer (score 2):

You could use 2 lines to get the effect you want:

```
    private void MainForm_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red);
        pen.DashStyle = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.Dot;
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, 0, 0, 50, 0 );
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, 0, 0, 0, 50);
    }
```

This draws the corner of a rectangle in the top left corner of the form.